I want the page to scroll smoothly to a specefic area on click
I have a React page with buttons at the top in the header.
What I want is to be able to make the page auto-scroll smoothly to a specific location of the react page when clicking on one of the buttons in the header.
I have a React page with buttons at the top in the header.
What I want is to be able to make the page auto-scroll smoothly to a specific location of the react page when clicking on one of the buttons in the header.
I used <button onClick={()=> window.location.replace('/#info')}>Info</button> to get to <h2 id='info'>ABOUT ME</h2>.
The result was that the page did go to the location, but it didn't scroll or smooth-scroll to the area.

You can achieve this by using HashRouter from react router dom along with tweenjs for animation, here is an example:
HashRouter v5 with tweenJs
const animateScrolling = useCallback(
(name) => {
  const coords = { y: window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset },
    target = document.getElementById(name.replace('/', ''));

  if (target) {
    // Create a new tween that modifies 'coords'.
    tweenRef.current = new Tween(coords)
      // Move to top of the clicked element in 700ms.
      .to({ y: elementOffsetTop(target).top + 10 }, scrollDuration)
      // Use an easing function to make the animation smooth.
      .easing(Easing.Quadratic.Out)
      .onUpdate(function () {
        // Called after tween.js updates 'coords'.
        // Move 'box' to the position described by 'coords' with a CSS translation.
        window.scrollTo(0, coords.y);
      })
      // Start the tween immediately.
      .start();

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
},
[animate, elementOffsetTop]

);
In this example I’m using react router dom v5 , if you would prefer to use react router dom v6, have a look at this repository:
HashRouter v6 with tweenJs
